# Property 'opacity' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes' throwing and error for view Opacity in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, eslint

After writing this sentence, typescript file shows an error on below line.

React-Native 0.60+
There is a new opacity prop that you can pass in:

```
<View opacity={true ? 0.5 : 1}> </View>
```

Error stack: error property 'opacity' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes view opacity.

No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ViewProps | Readonly): View', gave the following error. Type '{ children: Element; opacity: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Property 'opacity' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ViewProps, context: any): View', gave the following error.
Type '{ children: Element; opacity: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

How to resolve this warning, thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks to me like you're setting opacity as a boolean rather than a number. Double check how you're setting the opacity and maybe hardcode to 0.5 or something to see if it works?

Comment: What kind of code gives this error. It's quite hard to just guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this error by followin code :

```
<View style={{ opacity: true  ? 0.5 : 1 }}>
```

Happy Coding !